# Why is the plural form of "life" "lives", while the plural form of "still life" is "still lifes"?

Tags: grammatical-number, morphology, consonants

Why does the plural form of "life" is "lives", while the plural form of "still life" is "still lifes"?

From Wikipedia:

> A still life (*plural* **still lifes**) is a work of art depicting mostly
>   inanimate subject matter, typically commonplace objects which may be
>   either natural (food, flowers, plants, rocks, or shells) or man-made
>   (drinking glasses, books, vases, jewelry, coins, pipes, and so on).

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. You saved me from making a mistake (not that I speak of paintings that often, but still... )

Comment: Hello Paola, I am pleased to hear you. (I hope 'pleased' is the right word! I wont say 'piacere')

Comment: @Carlo_R. A slightly better phrasing might be "pleased to hear from you" since you're not actually physically hearing Paola

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say *still life* has undergone [reification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28linguistics%29), which transforms it into a "standalone word". How the subcomponent elements work grammatically doesn't automatically affect how the composite form works.

Effectively it's a kind of [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) - not really "new" today, but a lot later than the original word *life* with its irregular plural. Neologisms almost always have regular plural and verb forms.

Comment: The technical term is ***Reification.*** The lexical item has been reanalyzed as a separate word, in a separate context, and new words are regular, so it doesn't inherit the irregularities of the parent word. Similar reification accounts for the weirdness of _*New English Boiled Dinner_ and _*Toronto Maple Leaves._

Comment: @John: Thanks for that! - I knew what concept I was getting at, but I half-thought I had the wrong word. Will discard "grammaticalisation".

Comment: I was honestly unaware it was actually two words (I've always heard it pronounced, never read it).

Comment: _[Grammaticalization](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf)_ refers to a different phenomenon.

Comment: That Wikipedia article is about a completely different sense of the term "reification"; I think you might as well not link to it.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Not all new words are regular, and many formerly regular verbs have become irregular, with some variation between dialects. Consider *lighted→lit*, *sneaked→snuck*, *dived→dove*, *shitted→shat*, and *sended→sent*.

Comment: @ruakh: Could you perhaps find a better link?

Answer (score 7):

Irregular plurals and irregular deverbal nouns (i.e., nouns formed from verbs, like *house* /hauz/ from *house* /haus/) are frequently restricted in the way that your example and Barrie's *(computer) mouses* illustrate: the irregular form is only used for the most common meaning, with a fully regular form being used in neologisms and other variants.

Other examples are:

1. I might wonder when my computer was *hard-drived*, but not *hard-driven*.
2. If I hit someone with the sheath of a sword, I might be said to shea[θ] them, but not to shea[ð] them (which only means "to put a sword in its sheath").
3. When the evil witch gets squashed with a house in *The Wizard of Oz*, she might be said to get hou[s]ed, but not hou[z]ed (which only means "to provide with housing").
4. When *bad* measures street cred, its superlative is *baddest*, not *worst*.
5. The past tense of *input* is, for many people, *inputted* (as in *Who inputted these data?*), even though the past tense of *put* is just *put*.

Comment: Nice answer, but the evil witch is hou[s]ed at the beginning of the wizard of oz.

Comment: @Jake223 Thanks.  Simpler just to say "in".

Answer (score 6):

Because *still lifes* are not the same thing as *still lives*. Similarly, *mouses* are not the same thing as *mice*.

Comment: What are 'mouses' then?

Comment: I've encountered *mouses* as a verb form, but not as a plural noun.

Comment: @Mitch: Computer pointing devices.

Comment: Oh. OK. I always called them 'mice', but I guess I've heard the alternative you gave, too.